# querying data with checkboxes only correctly works with one group of checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql

This works as long as I select at least one checkbox from the Story category. If no checkboxes from Story are checked and I check any other categories, nothing is returned.

I'd really like to know what it's causing such a weird error.

homes database is in this order:
homes_id 
name
story
bedroom
bath

Edit: I asked a previous part of this question before but now I'm dealing with another obstacle
Edit: Forgot to add $valid_responses to foreach

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Homes Test 2</title> 
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

    <p>
        <h3>story</h3>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="story[]" value="1" id="story_1" />one story</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="story[]" value="2" id="story_2" />two story</label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <h3>bedrooms</h3>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="bedroom[]" value="2" id="bed_2" />two beds</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="bedroom[]" value="3" id="bed_3" />three beds</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="bedroom[]" value="4" id="bed_4" />four beds</label>
    </p>

    <p>
        <h3>baths</h3>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="bath[]" value="1" id="bath_1" />one bath</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="bath[]" value="2" id="bath_2" />two baths</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="bath[]" value="3" id="bath_3" />three baths</label>
    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="search" />

</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['story'])) {

    DEFINE ('DB_USER', 'root'); 
    DEFINE ('DB_PASSWORD', 'testpass'); 
    DEFINE ('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); 
    DEFINE ('DB_NAME', 'homes');

    $dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) OR die ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
    $q = "SELECT name, story, bedroom, bath FROM homes WHERE 1";

    // Protect against injection attacks
    $valid_responses = array(
        'bedroom' => array(
            '1','2'),
        'story' => array(
            '1','2'),
        'bath' => array(
            '1','2','3'),
    );
    foreach ($valid_responses as $field=>$values) {
        $selection = array_intersect($_POST[$field],$values);
        if (!empty($selection)) {
            $q .= ' AND ' . $field . ' IN ("' . implode('", "', $selection) . '")';
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
        }else{
            echo "selection was empty";
        }
    }
    while($data = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $data;
    }

    echo json_encode($rows);

    echo "<pre>$q</pre>";
}



?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct, because you started by checking:

```
if (isset($_POST['story'])) {
```

You can include other checkboxes like this one:

```
if (isset($_POST['story']) || isset($_POST['bedroom']) || isset($_POST['bath']) {
```

It depends on your goal.

Comment: Thank you @Akam that fixed it. Still would be interested to know how the other categories worked as long as one checkbox was checked in story category.